# не работает условие if/else

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Занумаюсь автоматизацией тестирования. ВебДраивер+Ява.
PageObject+PageFactory.

Вот код для пейджи:

```
public ManageSubscriptionsTab hitResumeButtonIfDisplayed ( ){
        if (resumeSubscriptionButton.isDisplayed()){
            resumeSubscriptionButton.click();
        }
        else {cancelSubscriptionButton.click();}
        return this;
    }
```

пробовал еще вот так:

```
public ManageSubscriptionsTab hitResumeButtonIfDisplayed (boolean value ){
    if (resumeSubscriptionButton.isDisplayed() == value){
        resumeSubscriptionButton.click();
    }
    else {cancelSubscriptionButton.click();}
    return this;
}
```

Суть, если нет кнопки на странице - нажать другую кнопку. Но почему-то драивер деиствие не выполняет, точнее выполняет, но не верно. Пишет не могу найти кнопку(resumeSubscriptionButton), но по логике теста если ее нет, надo жать другую кнопку(cancelSubscriptionButton), но он ее не жмет, а все еще ищет первую.

вот для  теста:

```
@Test
    public void cancelSubscription (){
        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        ManageSubscriptionsTab manageSubscriptionsTab = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ManageSubscriptionsTab.class);
        loginPage.logInToTheAccount("","");
        driver.get("https://.../manage-subscription");

        manageSubscriptionsTab.hitResumeButtonIfDisplayed(); 

        WebDriverWait wait = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/div[2]/standard-form/form/div/div/button")));

        manageSubscriptionsTab.clickSubmitCancellation(); 

        Assert.assertTrue(manageSubscriptionsTab.yellowContainerIsDisplayed());
        String textContainer = manageSubscriptionsTab.whenTheSubscriptionIsCanceledText();
        Assert.assertEquals("Your subscription has been canceled. " +
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861143/4928642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if (resumeSubscriptionButton.isDisplayed()){
> ```

Логично что `.isDisplayed()` проверяет существующий объект на видимость. А тебе надо проверять на наличие в DOM:

```
if (resumeSubscriptionButton.isPresent()){
```

Comment: не совсем понятно.

Comment: Ответ дополнен.

Comment: Спасибо за наведение в верное русло!

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал вот так:

```
public boolean resumeButtonIsDisplayed() {
    return resumeButton.size()>0 == true;
}

public ManageSubscriptionsTab hitResumeButtonifDisplayed (  ) {
    if (resumeButtonIsDisplayed()== true){
        resumeSubscriptionButton.click();
    }
    else {
        cancelSubscriptionButton.click();
    }
    return this;
}
```

где для true применяется список элементов.